# How to authenticate a ldap user from any ldap server (except embedded server) using bind authentication mechanism in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, spring-security-ldap, ldapauth

I want to implement ldap authentication in an existing spring boot project for my company. So for that I am trying to implement one sample spring boot app first, in which I will authenticate a ldap user from my company ldap server. If it works, fine then I will implement the same code into my existing project and I want to achieve this using ldap bind authentication mechanism only.

Following is the code to authenticate a ldap user using bind authentication mechanism in spring security that I have written for my sample app:

[Here is the server structure for user, from this image you will get idea what are attribute available for an user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njTW3.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleApp2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SampleApp2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
                        <version>5.5.3</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.example.SampleApp2;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String index() {
    return "Welcome to the home page!";
  }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.example.SampleApp2;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public XyzEncryption xyzEncrption() { // custom password encoder which is used in company's ldap server to authenticate user, even though I didn't use it any where
    
        return new XyzEncryption();
    }
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin();
  }
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .ldapAuthentication()     
    .contextSource()
    .url("ldap://in.xyz.com:389/DC=in,DC=xyz,DC=com")
    .managerDn("CN=Rohit Sarkar,OU=Engg,OU=KSPL Users,DC=in,DC=xyz,DC=com") //User Dn by which I am binding the connection with server
    .managerPassword("PasswordOfRohitSarkar")
    .and()
    .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName=abdulg")
    .userDnPatterns("CN=Abdul Gaffar,OU=Engg,OU=KSPL Users,DC=in,DC=xyz,DC=com"); // User dn which need to be authenticated from server      
  }
}
```

[I am getting this kind of default login page from spring security and loging with abdulg and it's password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVJm.png)

But getting error:

```
org.springframework.ldap.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); nested exception is javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name ''
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:216) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:385) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:197) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:223) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:203) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:83) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364) [catalina.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.70]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_302]
Caused by: javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3024) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2998) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1874) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1797) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:322) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

I have used follwoing instead of hard coding:

```
.userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
```

Still getting same error.

I have tried ad authentication provider to authenticate the user and its being authenticated successfully, but since it's not a standard way in spring security, I want to use bind authentication and don't want to use password compare authentication. I want to keep user's password hidden.

Following is the code to authenticate user using ad authentication provider:

```
package com.example.SampleApp2;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public KovairEncryption kovairEncrption() {
    
        return new KovairEncryption();
    }
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
  }
  
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
        new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("in.xyz.com", "ldap://in.xyz.com")
        authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

I have also tried traditional java code to authenticate ad user it was also working fine but unable to authenticate using bind authentication mechanism. I have read lot of articles and have gone through lot of spring reference document but couldn't find any solution. I have already spent almost one week to get a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So after spending lot of times I got solutions.

**First of all, there is nothing wrong with the code snippet mentioned above, reason of this error is-**

[Accroding to spring security doc under section 18.4.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html), In case of active directory search, after authenticating the user successfully, the `LdapAuthenticationProvider` will attempt to load a set of authorities for the user by calling the configured `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` bean. The `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` is an implementation which will load the authorities by searching the directory for groups of which the user is a member (typically these will be groupOfNames or groupOfUniqueNames entries in the directory).

If you want to use LDAP only for authentication, but load the authorities from a difference source (such as a database) then you can provide your own implementation of this interface and inject that instead.

But I was ignoring the authorities which was returning after successfull authentication of the user, that is why I was getting this error.

**There are few ways to solve the problem:**

**1st Way:** using `Context.REFERRAL` to `follow`

**Disadvantage:** it will take lot of time to follow the referral and authenticate user

**2nd Way:** By implementing `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`

CustomAuthoritiesPopulator.java

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations dco, String string) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
    
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Autowired
CustomAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiespopulator;
```

```
// I have mentioned only configure() method here, others code will be as it is

@Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .ldapAuthentication()     
    .contextSource()
    .url("ServerUrl")
    .managerDn("BindUserDN") 
    .managerPassword("BindUserPassword")
    .and()
    .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(authoritiespopulator)
    .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName=UserName")
    
  }
```

**Note:** This will be helpful if you want set some custom authority

**3rd Way:** Using `.setIgnorePartialResultException(true)`

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Bean
LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() {
   LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
   ldapContextSource.setUrl("ServerUrl");
   ldapContextSource.setUserDn("BindUserDN");
   dapContextSource.setPassword("BindUserPassword");
   ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
}

@Bean
public LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator() throws Exception { 
DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiespopulator= new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapContextSource(), "base");
        authoritiespopulator.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        return authoritiespopulator;
    }

@Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .ldapAuthentication()     
    .contextSource()
    .url("ServerUrl")
    .managerDn("BindUserDN") 
    .managerPassword("BindUserPassword")
    .and()
    .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(authoritiespopulator)
    .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName=UserName")
    
  }
```